# C++ Linked list with STRING elements. Delete all strings of maximum length from it,and display the contents of the modified list

Tags: c++

This is what I made (finds the maxim size of entered string). Now I have to write this program with linked list (to show,delete and show the modified list). I didn't really understand nodes and that stuff.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n, msize = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::string a[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
        if(a[i].length() > msize) msize = a[i].length();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(a[i].length() == msize) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you saw something like `struct node { std::string data; node* next; };`? What part is it that you don't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: Unrelated: `std::string a[n];` is a [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) and it's not valid in standard C++. Use : `std::vector<std::string> a(n);` instead.

Comment: @Antonio Margina The C++ Standard already provides two lists std::forward_list and std::list.:) You can use them.